# Speed and Performance-Tuning tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Is the [speed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed) tag sufficiently differentiated from the [performance-tuning](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning) tag to warrant keeping it?

---

In the three years since I posted this question the tags have remained separate.  Perhaps now there is enough experience and habit to make a clear decision on this matter.  Please post your argument either way as an answer than may be Accepted.

Comment: I don't think so. Although I recently approved an excerpt edit for their efforts, I do think it should be made a synonym of performance-tuning.

Comment: Agreed- and having the synonym would be a benefit

Comment: Also agree. If at some point we'd need to differentiate between various types of performance-tuning, we can always do so, but right now I don't see such a need.

Comment: Nope. Synonimize away!

Comment: Hmm... There are certainly times when "performance tuning" involves the reduction of the memory consumed by your code.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I think that's a good point! If we keep a more general [tag:performance-tuning], we will cover all cases.

Comment: I'd say make speed a synonym of master performance_tuning

Comment: +1 for synonym.

Comment: @Sjoerd Please post that as an answer so people can vote for it, and so that it can be Accepted.

Comment: @Mr.wizard OK, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say make speed a synonym of master performance_tuning. The other way around would certainly be wrong as speed is just one of the possible tunings (memory, complexity, development time, training time in the case of machine learning etc.).